# This unit test regarding a RunTimeException doesn't make any sense to me

Tags: java, spring, rest, unit-testing, junit

I'm workin on a Spring Boot CRUD RESTful API with an **User** entity that consists of an `id` and a `name` parameter.

I have possible *UserNotFound* error i.e. *RunTimeException* on endpoints that depend upon an `id` to be found, such as : *List an user*, *Delete an user* and *Update an user*.

So on my unit tests, i should also test if the *RunTimeException* is being thrown correctly, right? That's what i'm trying to do, and my tests passed but i can't seem to understand why, it doesn't seem right to me.

My *DeleteUserServiceTest* :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class DeleteUserServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private DeleteUserService deleteUserService;

    @Test
    public void whenGivenId_shouldDeleteUser_ifFound(){
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("Test Name");
        user.setId(1L);

        when(userRepository.findById(user.getId())).thenReturn(java.util.Optional.of(user));

        deleteUserService.deleteUser(user.getId());
        verify(userRepository).deleteById(user.getId());
    }

    @Test(expected = RuntimeException.class)
    public void should_throw_exception_when_user_doesnt_exist() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(89L);
        user.setName("Test Name");

        given(userRepository.findById(anyLong())).willReturn(Optional.ofNullable(null));
        deleteUserService.deleteUser(user.getId());
    }
}
```

This is my service, that's being tested :

```
@Service
public class DeleteUserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository repository;

    public void deleteUser(Long id) {
        Optional<User> userOptional = repository.findById(id);
        if (!userOptional.isPresent()) {
            throw new UserNotFoundException(id);
        } else {
            repository.deleteById(id);
        }
    }
}
```

And the UserNotFound tidbit of code :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class UserNotFoundAdvice {

    @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler(UserNotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    String userNotFoundHandler(UserNotFoundException ex) {
        return ex.getMessage();
    }
}

public class UserNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
    public UserNotFoundException(Long id) {
        super("Could not find user with id " + id + ".");
    }
}
```

Would appreciate if someone could spare some time to explain what i'm doing right and what i'm doing wrong here. It seems i struck a wall and can't go any further without some assistance.

Comment: Your advice does nothing (that is for the controller). You check a runtime exception and that is succeeding because `UserNotFoundException` is a `RuntimeException`. So not sure what it is you are confused about. (Also generally speaking using `isPresent` is the sign you are doing something wrong with an optional).

Comment: @M.Deinum I think my advice is supposed to render an HTTP 404 when an UserNotFoundException is thrown, not sure if it's doing nothing the way you said, could you elaborate on this and the isPresent statement, please?

Comment: You aren't testing web related classes so your advice, for your test, doesn't add anything.  Use `map(deleteById).orElseThrow()`. Abusing optional for an if is basically something you shouldn't be doing.